# Python: Unresolved reference in try catch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I'm trying to use accumulator (variable) inside the except/else:

## Updated code

```
classifier = UtteranceClassifier()

sc = SparkContext("local[2]")

offensives = sc.accumulator(0)
total = sc.accumulator(0)

# Create Spark session
def get_spark_session():
    return SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .master(master) \
        .appName(appName) \
        .getOrCreate()


def classify(utterance):
    global offensives
    global total

    total += 1
    print("total: ", total)
    try:
        return classifier.classify(utterance)
    except Exception:
        offensives += 1
        print("offensives: ", offensives)



def main():
    spark: SparkSession = get_spark_session()

    ....

    # Clean text
    df_clean = df.select((f.lower(f.regexp_replace('utterance', "[^a-zA-Z\\s]", "")).alias('utterance_text')))

    # Tokenize text
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol='utterance_text', outputCol='utterance_token')
    df_words_token = tokenizer.transform(df_clean).select('utterance_token')

    # Remove stop words
    remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol='utterance_token', outputCol='utterance_clean')
    df_no_stopwords = remover.transform(df_words_token).select('utterance_clean')
    #df_no_stopwords.show(truncate=False)

    classify_udf = f.udf(classify, StringType())
    # Classify utterance
    df_no_stopwords = df_no_stopwords.withColumn("offensive", classify_udf(f.col('utterance_clean')))
    df_no_stopwords.show(truncate=False)

    print("Offensives: ", offensives.value)
    print("Total: ", total.value)
```

I have such compilation error on both variables total & offensives:

> Inspection info: this inspection detects names that should resolved but don't...

Comment: Please post the actual code not just the picture

Comment: No images: post your code and relevant errors as *text*.

Comment: Seems like you are are trying to do `c` programming in `python`. There is no such syntax like `num_of_offensive++` or `total++`. exist in python.

Comment: same if I use: num_of_offensive=num_of_offensive+1 !!

Comment: Problem with the scope of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't have a `++` operator. You could you the `+=` operator instead:

```py
def classify(utterance):
    try:
        classifier.classify(utterance)
    except Exception:
        num_of_offensive += 1
    else:
        total += 1
```

Comment: Still having same error "Unresolved reference" on these variables even with +=

Comment: @zbeedatm please share the exact error you get after updating the code

Comment: Compilation error: Inspection info: this inspection detects names that should resolved but don't

Comment: If you set `total = total + 1` (or `total += 1`) you create a local variable `total`(to be precise: you bind the local name `total` to the result of `total + 1`). Now Python knows that `total` is a local variable an tries to use it in `total + 1`. But you never defined a local variable `total` ans so you get an error. Fix: If you have `total` in the outer scope pass it in as a parameter and return the new total. The same applies to `num_of_offensive`.

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't do that, cause it's a Spark accumulator, and the whole idea to increase it when there is an exception. I'll update my code with the line calling this method on a dataframe

Comment: That's the moment where the evil `global` comes into play. Write the two lines `global total` and `global num_of_offensive` as the first lines in your function, then Python will know that you intend to use the variables from the global scope. Please try to keep down the usage of `global`. It leads to functions that depend heavily on the rest of the program.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but when printing both values at the end I'm getting zero! inside the classify method It's getting accumulated!

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the if/else with try/except.  Do it like this:

```
    def classify(utterance):
        try:
            classifier.classify(utterance)
            total += 1
        except:
            num_of_offensive += 1
```